# Expand compact data

Tags: mariadb

For the sake of simplicity, I decided to store a value only when it changes.

```
+------------+--------+-------+
|    date    | entity | value |
+------------+--------+-------+
| 2019-01-01 |      1 |    10 |
| 2019-01-01 |      2 |    15 |
| 2019-01-01 |      3 |    11 |
| 2019-02-12 |      1 |     9 |
| 2019-03-01 |      2 |    13 |
| 2019-03-05 |      1 |    10 |
| 2019-03-05 |      3 |    10 |
+------------+--------+-------+
```

But on a day to day basis, I need to work with the current value at any given date, essentially converting the previous table (ideally as a view) to:

```
+------------+----------+----------+----------+
|    date    | entity-1 | entity-2 | entity-3 |
+------------+----------+----------+----------+
| 2019-01-01 |       10 |       15 |       11 |
| 2019-01-02 |       10 |       15 |       11 |
|    ...     |    ...   |    ...   |   ...    |
| 2019-02-11 |       10 |       15 |       11 |
| 2019-02-12 |        9 |       15 |       11 |
| 2019-02-13 |        9 |       15 |       11 |
|    ...     |    ...   |    ...   |   ...    |
| 2019-02-28 |        9 |       15 |       11 |
| 2019-03-01 |        9 |       13 |       11 |
| 2019-03-02 |        9 |       13 |       11 |
| 2019-03-03 |        9 |       13 |       11 |
| 2019-03-04 |        9 |       13 |       11 |
| 2019-03-05 |       10 |       13 |       10 |
| 2019-03-06 |       10 |       13 |       10 |
| 2019-03-07 |       10 |       13 |       10 |
| 2019-03-08 |       10 |       13 |       10 |
+------------+----------+----------+----------+
```

Or if its easier, simply get the values for a given date and basically getting a single row.

Ive been looking at the [Window Functions](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/window-functions/) and this excellent [Pivot tutorial](https://modern-sql.com/use-case/pivot), but so far no luck...

Comment: Which version of MariaDB?

Comment: Latest version 10.3

Answer (score 0):

A sparsed ditto-table can be converted into the full-range view by the user-defined variables like that:

```
SELECT a.date
       IF(b.value IS NULL, @e1, @e1 := b.value) AS entity1
       IF(c.value IS NULL, @e2, @e2 := c.value) AS entity2
       IF(d.value IS NULL, @e3, @e3 := d.value) AS entity3
  FROM fullrange AS a  -- single-column auxiliary table with all the dates in the range
  LEFT JOIN tbl  AS b  ON b.date = a.date AND b.entity = 1    -- for entity-1  
  LEFT JOIN tbl  AS c  ON c.date = a.date AND c.entity = 2    -- for entity-2
  LEFT JOIN tbl  AS d  ON d.date = a.date AND d.entity = 3    -- for entity-3  
 ORDER BY a.date ASC
```

The only requirement is that all entities should have the not-NULL value for the first day of the range.

Answer (score 0):

**Sequence engine**

Here's a solution utilising MariaDB's special [sequence storage engine](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/sequence-storage-engine/) (installed by default from 10.1) to create the date range. You can change `seq_0_to_70` to fit the date range you need in your use case.

```
SET @entity_1 := NULL, @entity_2 := NULL, @entity_3 := NULL;

SELECT q2.date, 
    @entity_1 := IFNULL(q2.entity_1, @entity_1) entity_1,
    @entity_2 := IFNULL(q2.entity_2, @entity_2) entity_2,
    @entity_3 := IFNULL(q2.entity_3, @entity_3) entity_3
FROM (
  SELECT q1.date, 
    max(IF(t1.entity=1, t1.value, NULL)) entity_1, 
    max(IF(t1.entity=2, t1.value, NULL)) entity_2, 
    max(IF(t1.entity=3, t1.value, NULL)) entity_3 
  FROM (
        SELECT '2019-01-01' + INTERVAL seq DAY as `date` 
        FROM seq_0_to_70
  ) q1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN t1 ON q1.date=t1.date
  GROUP BY q1.date 
) q2
ORDER BY q2.date;
```

Here's a [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=508477f86296d499d16941d5953069b8) for evidence.

**Recursive CTE**

If instead you'd prefer a solution that is more standards compliant and also works with MySQL 8, try something like this, where the date range is generated by a [recursive CTE](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/recursive-common-table-expressions-overview/). This requires MariaDB 10.2 or later.

```
SET @entity_1 := NULL, @entity_2 := NULL, @entity_3 := NULL;

SELECT q2.date, 
  @entity_1 := IFNULL(q2.entity_1, @entity_1) entity_1,
  @entity_2 := IFNULL(q2.entity_2, @entity_2) entity_2,
  @entity_3 := IFNULL(q2.entity_3, @entity_3) entity_3
FROM (
  SELECT q1.date, 
    max(IF(t1.entity=1, t1.value, NULL)) entity_1, 
    max(IF(t1.entity=2, t1.value, NULL)) entity_2, 
    max(IF(t1.entity=3, t1.value, NULL)) entity_3 
  FROM (
    WITH RECURSIVE dates AS (     
      SELECT '2019-01-01' AS date  
      UNION ALL     
      SELECT dates.date + INTERVAL 1 DAY AS date
      FROM dates
      WHERE dates.date < '2019-03-12'
    ) 
    SELECT d.date
    FROM dates d
  ) q1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN t1 ON q1.date=t1.date
  GROUP BY q1.date 
) q2
ORDER BY q2.date;
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fa2a65eb03a7edfbd96d0a409c9f0c1e) here.